# Is computing in Star Wars ubiquitous?

Tags: star-wars

Is ubiquitous computing seen in the world of Star Wars? Are there computers everywhere?

Comment: What precisely is implied by *ubiquitous*? Every planet, city, ship?

Comment: Besides the walking, talking, robots with AI walking around everywhere?

Comment: Do you mean like the Internet of Things?

Comment: There aren't any computers in interstellar space or in the middle of stars. That would be ubiquitous.

Answer (score 3):

> Are [there] computers everywhere?

### No.

Ewoks don't have any computers.

> Is ubiquitous computing seen in the world of Star Wars?

### Yes.

Of the societies that do have computers, there doesn't appear to be much difference between species and planets. All the protocol droids and astromec droids seem to operate around the same capacity. I don't recall ever hearing about any group having some sort of computing technological advantage over another one.